# Can anyone please tell what this bytecode does?

Tags: java, android, bytecode

```
            // Byte code:
            //   0: aload_0
            //   1: monitorenter
            //   2: aload_0
            //   3: getfield 17 me/empirical/android/application/fillmemory/MainActivity$4$1:this$1 Lme/empirical/android/application/fillmemory/MainActivity$4;
            //   6: getfield 28 me/empirical/android/application/fillmemory/MainActivity$4:this$0   Lme/empirical/android/application/fillmemory/MainActivity;
            //   9: bipush 10
            //   11: aload_0
            //   12: getfield 17    me/empirical/android/application/fillmemory/MainActivity$4$1:this$1 Lme/empirical/android/application/fillmemory/MainActivity$4;
            //   15: getfield 28    me/empirical/android/application/fillmemory/MainActivity$4:this$0   Lme/empirical/android/application/fillmemory/MainActivity;
            //   18: invokestatic 34    me/empirical/android/application/fillmemory/MainActivity:access$300 (Lme/empirical/android/application/fillmemory/MainActivity;)Landroid/widget/Button;
            //   21: invokestatic 38    me/empirical/android/application/fillmemory/MainActivity:access$100 (Lme/empirical/android/application/fillmemory/MainActivity;ILandroid/widget/Button;)V
            //   24: aload_0
            //   25: monitorexit
            //   26: return
            //   27: astore_1
            //   28: aload_0
            //   29: monitorexit
            //   30: aload_1
            //   31: athrow
            //   32: astore_1
            //   33: goto -9 -> 24
            // Local variable table:
            //   start  length  slot    name    signature
            //   0  36  0   this    1
            //   27 4   1   localObject Object
            //   32 1   1   localException  Exception
            // Exception table:
            //   from   to  target  type
            //   2  24  27  finally
            //   24 26  27  finally
            //   28 30  27  finally
            //   2  24  32  java/lang/Exception
```

This code was part of an android application which is used to fill the ram memory. This code was present in the function to fill 10 mb of ram memory. Can anybody please explain its working as I have no experience with bytecode and please suggest few sites to grasp quick bytecode knowledge. Thank you.

Comment: Search jvm instruction set or such will find sufficient sites, monitorenter/exit is a `synchronized` block; nothing troublesome happens.

Comment: There are tools that can help disassemble it for you.

Comment: seems like this should go on RE stack exchange.

Answer (score 2):

A `bytecode` is instructions set of **JVM(Java Virtual Machine)**. Java programmer does not really have to understand `bytecode`. JVM uses `bytecode` to make a javaprogram portable,thats mean it can be run on any platform(Windows,MAC,UNIX,LINUX.........).

JRE on a platform interprets bytecode and convert it to local ObjectCode of the platform.

you can refer to [This Link](http://www.cubrid.org/blog/dev-platform/understanding-jvm-internals/)
for more details

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the name `MainActivity$4$1`, this code must have come from a method in a *nested* anonymous class inside `MainActivity`.

The Java code should be something like this:

```
synchronized (this) {
    try {
        methodInMainActivity(MainActivity.this, 10, methodThatReturnsButton(MainActivity.this));
    } catch (Exception localException) {}
}
```

You can find many Java bytecode tutorials on the Internet. However, the ultimate reference is this: [The Java Virtual Machine Instruction Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html).